# MVVM with Android Architecture Components

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm exploring the new Android Architecture Components and looking to implement it into an Android app. I am firmillair with MVVM as I use the paradigm on iOS development. Having read through the Android Architecture Components guide, provided by Google: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

I have just a few questions...

In the above mentioned guide, Google use the `UserRepository` class that access these web service API - they go on to make this class a `Singleton` which is probably fine, if there were only ever one screen on the app that needed data from a REST API.

My concern, is this; it seems Google advocate the need to create a repository class on a per-ViewModel basis. This sounds very wrong to me, in having so many `Singlton` classes in the app. If we were to have 10 screens, with ten ViewModels - each needing its own `Repository module` - we then have ten singletons in our app. From an iOS dev perspective, this is wrong to have so many.

The solution to this, would be to have one mediator (Repository) class, that has public methods, exposing the API to get data from a REST API. The Web service part, would be in its own class. That way, we have a decent separation of concerns.

Is it best practice, to have one repository class, per, ViewModel - or to have one per app? I'm not 100% sure on this.

Lastly, I have the same concern when it comes to `Room`- is Google saying we create a DB on a per ViewModel bases or just one DB per app?

Comment: You're really reading far too much into a simple page with a trivial example.  The architecture they set up will work fine for some apps, and not for others.  Think more for yourself about what makes sense, and less copy paste of a guide.

Comment: The intention was not a copy-paste. But I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the architecture guide suggests to create a separate repository class for each ViewModel. In the example that is shown Google uses a library called Dagger to inject the singleton repository class into the ViewModel. It is normally best practice to split repositories (or managers) on functionality. UserRepository is responsible for all user related api calls for example.

If you turn this repository into a singleton that you can inject in any ViewModel, any ViewModel now has access to that specific repository.

After quickly looking into Room I found this little snippet ([link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)):

> **Note**: You should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object, as each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances.

This to me means that you can implement the RoomDatabase much in the same way you can use your repository classes. Simply inject them as a singleton into your ViewModel so you don't need to have multiple instances of the same database.

Comment: Thanks for the info; that does indeed make sense. To go on from there, lets say we have many different REST APIs in the app - and no two, give the same type of data. Would it then be best to group these APIs by functionality and put them into related repos? 

I suppose, the same could be said for the Room DB. Lets say the app, access a Weather API and the latest Motorsports API - unrelated data - so they need separate ViewModels. Do we then need two Room DB's and two repose in this case?

Comment: @Tander For the first scenario, two different rest APIs, you would probably look at the data rather than the actual endpoint that you talk to. You kind of want ViewModels to be agnostic about the source of the data, all a ViewModel wants to do is say; weatherRepo.getWeather() or something like that. If you have a different data source that gets related data from a different endpoint, I would put it in the same repo. If it's different data I'd put it in a different repo. It's not about the source it's about the datatype.

Comment: @Tander The second scenario isn't really realistic, what is the point of having two completely separate local databases? I'd merge it all in the same room database (of course with the correct relational setup)

Comment: The point about not looking at the end point, more so, the data type really clears it up for me, thank you. You're right, the ViewModel should not know, nor care, if the data it got, was from a REST API or a data cache, so the repo is perfect there. 

As for the second use case; I concur that it seems pointless to have more than one DB. And we would rather have one singleton Room DB, which can hold data about a list of friends AND the current weather (Two unrelated data types)

Comment: @Tander No problem! If the answer was correct, you can accept it if you want to ;). One tip too; the architecture components aren't fully supporting databinding yet, so you might run into some problems there.

Comment: Being pretty new to Android dev, I am not 100% what databinding is about. Will need to look into that, thanks for the heads up., if this doesn't work, I guess a good fall back solution is MVVM and RxJava (Without using App components )  and just forgoing the persistence for now (As that is not my biggest concern ) - Thanks again for being so helpful.